# PDO Execute appears to Bind Integer parameter as a string

Tags: php, pdo

PDO seems to add quotes to the bound parameters automatically in a prepared sql statement.

I do not want this functionality when I am trying to limit the number of results because this should be seen as an integer to mysql.

```
function fixStatistics($metal, $currency, $months){
$db = connectPDO();
$sql = '
        SELECT [COLUMN NAMES]
        FROM [TABLE NAMES]
        WHERE [WHERE STUFF]
        GROUP BY `Month`
        ORDER BY MONTH(DateStamp) LIMIT :numMonths
';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(
        array(
        ':metal' => $metal,
        ':currency' => $currency,
        ':numMonths' => $months // Problem Code
    )
);
$statistics = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $statistics;
}
```

I can resolve this issue by manually injecting / concatenating the sql statement - Not what I want to do.

```
ORDER BY MONTH(DateStamp) LIMIT ' . $numMonths
```

But is there a way of casting the :numMonths directly to an int at the point of `$stmt->execute();`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the docs about the execute array param:

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters
>   in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as
>   PDO::PARAM_STR.

use something like this before execute:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':numMonths', intval($months), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: please don't answer exact duplicates in the duplicate. add the answer to the existing question if you feel it is missing.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate earns one no reputation points.

Comment: @hakre - this question ranks higher than the original question for some Google queries. If duplicates are not to be deleted on SO, surely they should be answered?

Comment: @c.cam108 no, they should not. Answering them prevents from a (quicker) delete.

Comment: This is a solution, but what's strange to me is that PHP.net documentation shows an example using an int like this without problems:

$calories = 150;
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));

Maybe it works because of the comparison working with strings too.